# Batch loop over folder names sorting by date ignoring newer N elements

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, I have to make a batch in windows (.bat) to delete old folders in a backup disk.

I've made a script to delete folders individually:

**delete_single_folder.bat**

```
@echo off
if %1.==. goto usage
if exist %1\nul goto deldir
echo Folder %1 does not exists.
goto end
::------------------------------------------------
:deldir
rd /s/q %1
echo Folder %1 deleted.
goto :end
::------------------------------------------------
:usage
echo usage:
echo   %0 DIRNAME
echo.
echo Deletes the directory named DIRNAME and everything in it if it exists!
echo.
:end
```

As you can see in `::usage` it's executed via `delete_single_folder FOLDER_TO_DELETE`. Great.

---

Now, I get all folders sorted by date descending with:

```
dir /ad /b /O-D
```

And delete selected folders with a for-loop:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /ad /b /O-D') do ( 
     delete_single_folder %%i
)
```

That works great, problem is deleting ALL folders, and I want to ignore `N` records (days).

- There is a way to ignore last N folders with `dir` command to pass only older folders to for loop?

**ACTUAL OUTPUT for `dir /ad /b /O-D`**

```
20160211
20160210
20160209
20160208
20160207
20160206
20160205
20160204
20160203
20160202
20160201
20160131
```

But I want something like: `dir /ad /b /O-D` **`/ignore_first_5`**

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
20160206
20160205
20160204
20160203
20160202
20160201
20160131
```

Comment: Is N required to check the date ("ignore most recent 5 days") or just to say "ignore newest 5 folders"?

Comment: @lessthanideal sorting is guarantee because folders are created each night in a backup process... I just want to ignore first N elements of `dir` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can get that working by using **skip** option in for command.

syntax :

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=4" %a in ('dir /ad /b /O-D') do echo %a
```

Above command would skip first four folders from the output.

you can tweak the command according to your requirement

changes made to your code to get it working :

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=5" %%i in ('dir /ad /b /O-D') do ( 
 echo %%i
)
```

replace `echo %%i` with `RD` to delete folders , once you feel it is working as expected

Comment: super sweeet. That was exactly what I needed. THANKS!